# advanced custom fields checkbox in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields checkbox feature in WordPress for one of my custom post type. I have two items in the check box.

- Writer
- Criticizer

I only would like to print the right one which is chosen from WordPress admin panel. The filed name is `auth-trans`

I call it here in my code but it shows `array`, not the right one. Here's some of my code.

```
<div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ); 
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <a class="writer-link col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" href="<?php post_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="writer-row1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 image-right">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-right writer-content">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php if ( get_field('auth-trans') ) { 
                        echo '<h4>'.get_field('auth-trans').'</h4>';} ?>    
                    <?php if ( get_field('writer-bio') ) { 
                        echo '<p>'.get_field('writer-bio').'</p>';} ?>

                    <span>...</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>          

</div>
```

how can I fix it and where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try like this.

```
<?php the_field('auth-trans'); ?>
```

If you face any problem let me know.

Comment: do I write it in 'if' condition or when call 'auth-trans' field?

Comment: Yes you must use it in if condiiton.

Comment: Or you can use without if condition also. If the value is there it will display or it will not display anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo the field then replace

```
get_field('auth-trans')
```

With

```
get_field('auth-trans')[0]
```

Or you can also use

```
the_field('auth-trans');
```